# Generate Jetty MD5 Password without Java

Tags: java, unix, jetty, md5

I'm setting up a Jetty application that needs to declare account credentials in the `realm.properties` file. There are instructions for using the `org.mortbay.jetty.security.Password` class to generate credentials in a variety of forms, including MD5 hashes. In the example realm.properties, the file states that:

 `This entry is for digest auth.  The credential is a MD5 hash of username:realmname:password`

My question is, does anyone know the precise format used? I need to let my users send me password hashes for their account without requiring them to install both java and jetty. I'd imagine it should be as simple as figuring out the right combination of 'username' and 'password' to pipe to the unix `md5sum` utility.

I've looked at the source code for the `Password` class, and it appears to just hash the password by itself. Given that java strings are not ascii, perhaps I need to pipe the plain text through some unix utility? Something like `echo plaintext_passwd | some_format_translator | md5sum`?

For full credit, give me a unix command that will output a hash for "username" and "password" matching the MD5 output of `java -cp ./jetty-6.1.21.jar:./jetty-util-6.1.21.jar org.mortbay.jetty.security.Password username password` - which is `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`

EDIT: To be clear, it can be assumed my users have access to a fully-stocked Linux machine. They likely aren't running java, and definitely don't have a Jetty installation.

Comment: Have you considered using online md5 encoders? You do not programe anything. Users can do this by theirs own. Of course you need to considered security risk.

Comment: Link? I think the security implication is minimal here - even if the website stores it forever, they wouldn't know what I'm using it for, nor would they have access to the application. The tricky part is determining what the format is. I have yet to find an input to the md5sum utility that matches the Jetty output :-/

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple by using the md5sum command to generate a Jetty MD5 password.

1. Generate your password MD5 hash

   `echo -n "your-password" | md5sum`
2. Add MD5 hash to realm.properties

   `demo-user: MD5:b2bdfbbae9c3f49ac4ba0bfd8ba0ca6e, USER_ROLE1, USER_ROLE2`

Answer (score 0):

The class that does the lifting is here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Password.java